# Inserting something at the top of a word document and regretting it

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I have a bad habit of finding something like a table of data or a photo that I want to save in a new word document (immediate case, making a how-to for assembly of my P3AT), then just copy and insert into a new word document.

The problem is, that table has now altered the formatting of the top of the word document, and there's nothing I can do to get back to normal word typing up there.

I try putting my cursor as high top left as it will click, then press enter. It usually creates spaces and moves the table down, but all those empty spaces have an arrow off to the left and appear slightly grey because they are somehow similar to the table below.

I tried the accepted answers of CNTRL-SHIFT-ENTER, which also does a nice job of creating these pre-formatted blank lines.

The only solution I've found is to delete the document, open a new word document, hit enter at least once, and then DON'T EVER INSERT ANYTHING ON THE FIRST LINE! Do all my work, and when I'm all done, if I have to, I can take away the safety space at the top.

I have had similar troubles when inserting photos on the top line, where I can never get anything above it (I'll bet the CNTR-SHIFT-ENTER works for that).

There must something I've misunderstood about the situation, or there must be a simple way to get clean formatting back at the top. I guess copying the word document and deleting it isn't that hard, but it seems like an amateur solution.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried Ctrl+Enter? If that does not work please link a problem document

Comment: I've had this problem many times, and just got in the habit of never putting a table at the top of a document.

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl+Enter** takes you to the very beginning of a document.

**Ctrl+Z (Undo)** is your friend.

*If you want, save a document with the problem on DropBox or OneDrive and paste a view link here. I or others will be happy to give you specific directions.*
Here is an [Article on the Microsoft Answers site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/trouble-shooting-share-onedrive-file/a231a097-bcbf-4e34-ad6c-a33118baf471) that describes how to do this removing confidential information.